# How do I return the max value from multiple values in a single cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have some cells in my spreadsheet that have multiple dates separated by a semicolon `;`.

After some googling, I found that `TEXTSPLIT` is probably the best formula to break this apart, but it produces several columns of data. I'm hoping to compare the values within the cell before they are broken apart and return one value that is the greatest in the group.

Is this possible? One thing I just thought of is to have a bit of a convoluted machine that breaks out values in a separate sheet and another formula that takes the max value from those rows. Would like to avoid using multiple sheets if I can.

Here is the example:
[image: TextSplit formula example]

Comment: Try this way: `=MAX(TEXTSPLIT(A1,";")/1)` where cell `A1` refers to the cell reference where the dates are delimited using semicolon

Comment: Thanks for replying. Unfortunately that is not working. When I attempt to run just =MAX(TEXTSPLIT(A1, ";") it returns a value of 0. Adding the '/1' does not improve that.

Comment: Hey there, could you update your post with some sample dates as text so i copy and paste it in the excel to run a test

Comment: it seems those are formatted as text or they are having some white spaces you need to clean them based on the characters they have, since i dont see any sample data on the post, hence guessing it as white spaces then use `TRIM()` if not then special characters usually and common one, `SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(160),)+0`

Comment: Also I see there is difference in the formula, I have suggested and the one you have used. the delimiter i have used is secmicolon with a space while in yours its missing, could you try once. `=MAX(TEXTSPLIT(A1,"; ")/1)`

Comment: Maybe if I DATEVALUE between MAX and TEXTSPLIT. Trying that now.

Comment: You don;t show any sample so I am guessing only. Only one/two sample will be helpful. Also refer i answers i have posted some sample, is it similar like that?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Welcome to the Super User community! “You don;t show any sample so I am guessing only. Only one/two sample will be helpful.” You see where I commented “[And what have you done to achieve this?](https://superuser.com/questions/1830970/how-do-i-return-the-max-value-from-multiple-values-in-a-single-cell#comment2888336_1830970)” The reason questions like this are avoided/shunned is because lack of effort and lack of example. They are just begging for code without providing any effort or details. This is why I encourage you _not_ to answer them. As for clarification before.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Sir I completely agree with you, but I have seen, its not just for me, but I have seen in `Stackoverflow` as well as in `Superuser` where there is no attempt by OP, still they have gotten a solution. Also If I dont answer someone else will do it. But in this post has tried using `TEXTSPLIT()` so i have attempted with the last piece which they needed. Pardon me if I am wrong.

Comment: “but I have seen…where there is no attempt by OP, still they have gotten a solution.” Yes, those are mistakes. You should always ask for samples of data or effort to show code. Yes, you can assume things and assume a process but this site is not about “cheap” answers. Be thoughtful and careful when sharing your skills.

Comment: Sir all I agree with you. But there should be rule irrespective of any. The rule should be for everyone. Whatever you have said is right, I am not at all disagreeing you, but I have known the stack community from very long, and i still see people are doing that, very few asks, them. I can point many questions here, where questions are not properly asked yet they got solutions, even sometimes solutions are wrong still they got accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, then the following formula should work:

[image]

---

- Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

---

```
=MAX(--TEXTSPLIT(A1,"; "))
```

---

Or Using `BYROW()` to get all the output as once, without fill down!

[image]

---

```
=BYROW(A1:A3,LAMBDA(α, MAX(--TEXTSPLIT(α,"; "))))
```

---

With the existing sample data the above formula works as well, and here is a sample demonstration.

[image]

---

**Explanations:**

- Using `TEXTSPLIT()` function: it helps to split the strings by the delimiter `semi-colon with a space` --> `;`  across columns. (Please refer the `.gif` it shows).

Since its a function that falls under the function library **Text** hence one can realize that when used it will split the strings of dates as text, which creates a problem for future data manipulations, <sub>(**Note:** *In Excel dates and times are stored as numbers, therefore the integer part represents the dates while the decimal is the time for the date.*)</sub>

Hence as mentioned in OP by user using `DATEVALUE()` it can be converted to true dates or using `double unary` or by adding `0` or by multiplying by `1` or diving by `1`, which eventually converts.

---

- Once the above is done, then we can wrap it within `MAX()` function to return **latest/greatest/max/highest** (whichever suits in saying) date.

---

**Reasons:**

Why User was getting `0` while using the formula provided by me, while they were getting the respective output using `DATEVALUE()`, to explain, the screenshot clarifies it.

[image]

---

- User was using delimiter only semicolon `;` while I used semicolon and a space `;`
- So when when wrapping within `MAX()` with the double unary it was returning an error, as it was only converting the first one to a number while the second one was returning an error as it had a leading space. But the one with delimiter semicolon and space should work, refer screenshots.

[image]

---

- Using `DATEVALUE()` function it takes care of the leading space and converts the same to a number and lastly wrapping within `MAX()` gives the desired output. Alternative ways, are has been mentioned in the beginning using `;` , and another way to deal with it is using `TRIM()`

---

```
=MAX(--TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(A3,";")))
```

---

Comment: Thank you. What is the -- for in front of the TEXTSPLIT formula?

Comment: It means `--` double unary it converts numbers formatted as text to actual/true numbers that excel understand, in excel date/time are stored as numbers, so using `--` or `+0` or `/1` or `*1` it converts text formatted dates to true dates.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya You seem very smart and skilled. Do not fall into the trap of answering questions that show little to effort and don’t even show examples of data. You are falling into a trap. Maybe this answer will help the original poster, but in general you should ask for clarification and samples of data _before_ you post any answer. This is for everyone’s good especially you, the person spending precious time to post an answer.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Sir completely agree with you.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya I think you can back out of this specific question safely. But please be careful when answering questions in the future: They should show effort or (at least) show samples. Remember, your time and efforts have value. You answers are very good here; just be careful when you answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried [the answer provided by @MayukhBhattacharya](https://superuser.com/a/1830972/167207), but I do appreciate the information provided, so I gave the answer to that user.

I determined that the answers needed to be changed to a DateValue, so I inserted the DATEVALUE formula between the MAX and TEXTSPLIT formulas.

The formula I used was:

```
=MAX(DATEVALUE(TEXTSLIT(A2, ";")))
```

See example below:

[image: Incert DATEVALUE into formula]

Be sure to format the cell using the short date field.

Comment: `DATEVALUE` is not required, for any user around world using `Excel` for every dates/times are stored as numbers in Excel. The Integer part is the date while the decimal part is the time. So, when you are using text functions like `TEXTSPLIT()` to split, it formats the dates as text, to convert back them to numbers, you can use `DATEVALUE()` or a shorter way is of using `--` double unary or the other ways as explained in earlier comments. and then wrap within the aggregate functions like `MIN()` or `MAX()` to get desired output. To make it shorter i have used double unary

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I posted the answer because this is how I came to resolve this issue. It's probably not as slick nor is it using best practices which I'm sure yours is, but thought it might be a good/simple answer for beginners like myself. Thank you again for your feedback!

Comment: Ok, I have realized one thing, the `DATEVALUE()` helps in converting the text into actul dates here while double unary did for the first instance, this is because in your formula the delimiter you have used is `;` only semicolon, while i have used `; ` semicolon and the following space it carries. Also wrapping `TRIM()` would remove the leading space. `=MAX(--TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(A2,";")))`

Comment: Very cool, thank you for the clarification @Mayukh Bhattacharya